# Create CRUD UI in reactjs with backend api

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, react-router

Ive created a CRUD app in laravel, but now i want to improve the UI with react.js. Im still very new to react, so not sure how to go about doing this.

So far i have created a table component that displays all the users with react. how should i use react-router or whatever availble to implement `users/{id}`, `users/create`,  `users/{id}/edit`, etc so that when i click "show user" button, another component with user detail will appear to replace the users table in the same view.

One more question, how can i pass objects from backend to react view?

Thanks.

This is what i have right now:

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router'; 
import { Route, Link, RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

var FilterableTable = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: [],
      filterText: ''
    };
  },
  handleUserInput: function(filterText) {
    this.setState({
      filterText: filterText
    });
  },
  loadDataFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadDataFromServer();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
        />
        <ObjectTable
          data={this.state.data}
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
        />
        <RouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var NavBar = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function() {
    this.props.onUserInput(
      this.refs.filterTextInput.getDOMNode().value
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    return (

      <nav className="navbar">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
           <li>
              <Link to="/admin/users">All users</Link>
           </li>
           <li>
              <Link to="/admin/users/create">Create a user</Link>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <form className="form-group pull-right">
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            value={this.props.filterText}
            ref="filterTextInput"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </form>
      </nav>
    );
  }
});

var ObjectTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rows = [];
    this.props.data.forEach(function(object) {
      if (object.username.indexOf(this.props.filterText) === -1 &&     object.email.indexOf(this.props.filterText) === -1)
        return;
      rows.push(<ObjectRow object={object} key={object.uid}/>);

    }.bind(this));
    return (
      <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>ID</td>
              <td>Username</td>
              <td>Email</td>
              <td>Actions</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

var ObjectRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var objId = this.props.object.uid;

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.object.uid}</td>
        <td>{this.props.object.username}</td>
        <td>{this.props.object.email}</td>
        <td>
          <Link to="/admin/users/:objId" params={{objId: objId}} className="btn btn-small btn-success">Show</Link>
          <Link to="/admin/users/:objId/edit" params={{objId: objId}} className="btn btn-small btn-info">Edit</Link>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

var ShowObject = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

     return (

      <h1>showing a user</h1>
    );
  }
});


var routes = (
  <Route path="admin/users" handler={FilterableTable}>
    <Route path="/admin/users/:objId/edit" />
    <Route path="/admin/users/create" handler={CreateObject} />
    <Route path="/admin/users/:objId" handler={ShowObject} />
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {  
  React.render(<Handler url="/admin/get_users" />,  document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer your two questions:

1. React-router is pretty simple to use, and the documentation is
   great. You just have to create the different routes you want on the
   client-side. In your case you going to have three routes. The best is really to check the documentation which is really good about [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)
2. To get data from the backend, whether is it react or not, you
   have to use ajax. You can use jQuery and fetch some data from the
   `componentDidMount` method and updates the state of your react
   component accordingly. This is actually what you are doing and it
   works well. You might want to consider the Flux pattern to avoid
   having data management in your react components and have them being
   simple views in your system.

Comment: hey, i have the routes for the actions but i dont know how to go about doing component transition. say i have a component A displays all the users in a view. i want to hide the component A and display another component B displays user detail when i click a button. thanks.

Comment: You need to call a transition.  Basically each router handler is a view.  So when you transition it will just render a new view